# Connect dim ws As Worksheet with me.textbox

Tags: excel, vba

it is possible to connect worksheet like so? `const ws = me.textbox`

I would like to make a drop down list with possibility to chose worksheets in my user form.
I know that method won't work i pasted it below.

Is there any other possibility to make it work?

I use  `select case`but it means that i write my whole code **X times**

```
Sub Populate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = me.ChoseSheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assign text box value to string and then pass it to `set`

```
    strSheetName = Me.ChoseSheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `For each` loop to populate a `ComboBox` on a `UserForm`

For example:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws as WorkSheet

For each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Combobox1.AddItem(ws.Name)
next ws

End sub
```